# Webapp with root location other than /

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, pyramid

I'm using Pyramid, pserve (ran via Supervisord) and nginx. If I want my app to be available under location other than `/` (eg. `/xml/`) should I add prefix to routes in the app, or is there a way to set everything in nginx? Here's how I do it right now:

nginx:

```
location /xml {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6544;
}
```

Pyramid:

```
config.add_static_view('/xml/static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
config.add_route('system_admin', '/xml/admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best *not* to do this in nginx alone, because your webapp probably generates URLs of its own, and some of these might contain absolute paths. So if it thinks it's hosted at `/`, it will generate the wrong URLs, and nginx has no way to know.

If you really want to do it this way, you might try a rewrite rule like this:

```
location /xml {
  rewrite /xml(.*) $1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6544;
}
```